# How to solve kernel dying when running transformers? (python)

Tags: python, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to use transformers but kernel always dying when running the following code ;

```
# Load model directly
from transformers import AutoModel, AutoTokenizer
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained("dbmdz/bert-base-turkish-cased")
model = AutoModel.from_pretrained("dbmdz/bert-base-turkish-cased")
```

I dont understand, how can i solve this problem?

```
02:28:14.616 [info] Kernel process 30132.
02:28:15.235 [info] Restarted ab365139-165d-4145-95e4-b4a766e5975d
02:28:15.310 [info] Kernel acknowledged execution of cell 20 @ 1708298895310
02:28:42.134 [info] Start refreshing Kernel Picker (1708298922134)
02:28:43.141 [info] End refreshing Kernel Picker (1708298922134)
02:28:55.862 [info] End cell 20 execution after 40.552s, completed @ 1708298935862, started @ 1708298895310
02:31:40.979 [info] Handle Execution of Cells 3 for ~/Dev/search-gpt/bertorpic.ipynb
02:31:40.996 [info] Kernel acknowledged execution of cell 3 @ 1708299100996
02:31:59.839 [info] Handle Execution of Cells 21 for ~/Dev/search-gpt/bertorpic.ipynb
02:32:07.381 [info] End cell 3 execution after 26.385s, completed @ 1708299127381, started @ 1708299100996
02:32:07.393 [info] Kernel acknowledged execution of cell 21 @ 1708299127393
02:32:09.132 [error] Disposing session as kernel process died ExitCode: undefined, Reason: 
02:32:09.132 [info] Dispose Kernel process 30132.
02:32:09.152 [info] End cell 21 execution after -1708299127.393s, completed @ undefined, started @ 1708299127393
```

I tried ;

> conda install -c huggingface transformers

Comment: It dies when run within a notebook. Run it from the command line, and show us the stack trace.